# Xcode 8 Layout Issue - Why is the UITableCell contentView above the actual content?

Tags: ios, autolayout, xcode8

Xcode 8 Upgrade has broken many of my auto-layout settings - such a pain. Anyway - Here is a simple example. My UITableView was working fine - but since the upgrade now the images are missing - without any other changes being made to this table view. Investigation shows something really weird. Though the cell contains the image view and text with correct constraint etc within the cell layout (in pink)

The image view frame is seen above the cell...

[image: imageview frame]

Also when I click on content view the content is in the wrong place (shown in grey) - above the (pink) cell frame itself.

[image: content view]

My Image View Settings are:

[image]

For now the solution to displaying the missing images is to move the square frame down until in comes back into the pink area

Am I going crazy? Is this a bug caused in the Xcode 8 update? What should I do?

Comment: what happen if you run the project ? is it working fine in simulator or device ?

Comment: It runs fine on both device and simulator - I just cant see the image (as it is hidden above the cell)

Comment: then you may say it as issue of xcode!!!!!